# GC in while loop

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

I tried to run the following code on jenkins to convert a file to string and then convert the string to byte stream. The jenkins job failed because of OutOfMemoryError[java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space]. How can I do the garbage collection in the while loop to avoid OutOfMemoryError?

```
String content = steps.readFile("doc_html.tar.gz")
InputStream inp = null
inp = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))

byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead = -1;
while ((bytesRead = inp.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer);
}
outputStream.flush();
inp.close();
```

Comment: you read the entire file in memory, you need to change *that*, not mess with gc.

Comment: @luk2302 what is the alternative way? should I read the file by parts? How can I do it? Sorry I'm a newbie to this.

Comment: use some sort of `BufferedInputStream`, the `steps.readFile("doc_html.tar.gz")`is the problem.

Comment: @ luk2302 the problem for me is fileinputstream can't find the file in jenkins slave machine so the only way for me to read the file is steps.readFile(). If I want to use BufferedInputStream I need a input stream for the constructor, but I don't know how to create the input stream.

Comment: Are you using Jenkins Pipeline?

Comment: @StephenKing yes

Comment: Then this is really really bad.. Jenkins Pipeline has a DSL, including the [`readFile`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace) step that you should use. It might be that you also run into memory issues when reading large files, but "you can use groovy" does not mean "use plain Groovy" with Jenkins pipelines.

Comment: @StephenKing what is your recommendation? Should I use a downstream job to run a groovy script doing this work or ..?

Comment: Have you read and understood what Jenkins Pipeline is? Documentation at https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/

Comment: @StephenKing I actually  running it through a shared library.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm not sure about what you want to achieve. Maybe it's more efficient to use `sh`. See also [Best Practices for Scalable Pipeline Code](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/01/pipeline-scalability-best-practice/) "4. Prefer external scripts/tools for complex or CPU-expensive processing" as you are putting a lot of work on your master.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection is designed in a way, that when you are in the process of running out of memory, it will try to free more memory, if possible. So in most cases, if you run out of memory, it won't be, because the JVM did not call the garbage collector, but because you indeed use too much memory.
In your case, you read the entire file in the first line into memory. Afterwards you create an input stream from the bytes of your file in memory and process the bytes.
What would probably suit you more is to use a `FileInputStream` directly, to stream the bytes from the file and process them, instead of first caching the full file in a `String`.

Comment: I can't use FileInputStream at this case, because FileInputStream can't find the file in the workspace of jenkins slave machine, instead it can only find the file in jenkins' master server.

Comment: So how are you reading your file now (what type does `steps` have)? In my opinion it seems as if your jenkins setup is somehow flawed, the `FileInputStream` should actually work.

Comment: "Using java.io.File inside a Pipeline description cannot work as the Pipeline it self is executed on the Master when you want to write/read/test a file on the slave, where the build is done."   When I use FileInputStream, its constructor will create a file object using new File(filename) which will not read the file from the workspace.